# Does GeoServer support ST_GEOMETRY for SDE (Oracle)?

Tags: oracle, geometry, geoserver

I have an Oracle TABLE of spatial data that I want to serve as WFS using
 Geoserver. The geometries are stored in an Oracle table in ESRI
 ST_geometry format (ie, it comes from an ESRI SDE geodatabase).
 Can I serve these data using Geoserver?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You need to [install](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/arcsde.html#arcsde-install) the [ArcSDE extension](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/arcsde.html). You will need to add the ESRI `jsde_sdk.jar` & `jpe_sdk.jar` from your ArcSDE Java SDK media.

Comment: Thank you!!!, I could not found this files (jsde_sdk.jar & jpe_sdk.jar). Where I can found these files (jsde_sdk.jar & jpe_sdk.jar) ?

Comment: I'm not an ESRI user but those should be on the CDs that contain the ArcSDE Java SDK, alternatively you may be able to download them from ESRI

Comment: These two files are available on your installation of the ArcSDE Java SDK from the ArcSDE installation media (usually C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\ArcSDE\lib). They may also be available on ESRI’s website if there’s a service pack containing them, but this is not guaranteed